# Many postgres tables showing up empty in middle of session though no DML or DDL was executed

Tags: postgresql

In a given schema we can see the following tables:

[image]

The search_path is :

```
aact=# set search_path to public, ctgov                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ;
SET
```

[image]

The problem is that in the middle of a psql session a number of these tables just started showing zero rows. Then I exit'ed psql and restarted it: again those tables are still empty.

The interesting thing is this is not affecting *all* tables: see below:

[image]

I am not a regular user of postgres and have no clue what happened / is happening here. What should I look for?

Comment: Unrelated, but: are you aware that `count(1)` is [actually slower](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/09/19/whats-faster-count-or-count1/) than `count(*)` in Postgres?

Comment: ah ok as you can guess that's reflexes of >20 yrs of oracle.  look like it no longer matters for oracle either

Comment: `count(1)` was **never** faster in Oracle than `count(*)` - or any other DBMS actually, that's a myth that was never true.

Comment: When empty tables first appereared.. have you been in a transaction? Did you rollback this transaction? I feel like no and your data is somehow gone (at least in the perspective of the database, perhaps it is still on disk but marked as deleted). What have you done in this session? Is there any possibility, you deleted the entries, perhaps by calling a function?

Comment: No i was not doing any DML/ DDL.  I could not figure it out and ended up re-importing the database.

Comment: Look into the server log for weird messages. Is `zero_damaged_pages` set to `on`? Log all statements, and examine the log when it happens next.